# How do I perform git mv using Finder dragging files into new folders

Tags: git, github, finder

I'm doing cleanup organization tasks and it would be faster to just drag files into new folders via Mac OSX Finder than manually type out `git mv` for everything.  But git interprets Finder actions as a "delete" and new file instead of a "rename".

Can I instruct git to reinterpret these deletes as renames, or is there a way to attach git commands in Finder?

Comment: If you commit the changes it should show them as moves in the history. In the staging area it will show add/delete.

Comment: What exactly does 'git interprets Finder as a "delete" and new file instead of a "rename"' mean? Git doesn't track renames; it infers them based on file content. There's literally no difference between `git mv foo bar` and `git rm --cached foo; mv foo bar; git add bar`.

Comment: That's what I'm hoping, I want git to immediately infer this when I `git status`

Comment: Have you staged the changes yet? It should show renames after you do, assuming the content is similar enough (if you've just moved / renamed files without modifying them they certainly should be).